# Hyperlink cell in Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an `UltraGrid` which is bound to a `DataTable` with two columns (Key, Value). I have added 10 rows into the DataTable, and now the 11th row has a URL in the Value column. The URL value gets added fine, but it doesn't work like a hyperlink. To make it work as a hyperlink, how do I need to add this row into the UltraGrid?
My code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
ultraGrid.DataSource = dt;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

// Adding the row which has the URL value.
string url = "SomeURL";
Uri hyperLink = new Uri(url);
dt.Rows.Add("Click this", hyperLink);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answer given by U1199880 point to a partially correct solution there is a problem applying that style to the whole column. Every cell in the column will be treated as a link.

Instead you need to intercept the `InitializeRow` event and check if the current cell of the current row is a valid URI. Then change the cell Style property to the ColumnStyle.URL

```
private void grd_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ReInitialize == false)
    {
        UltraGridColumn c = e.Row.Band.Columns["Value"];
        string link = e.Row.GetCellValue(c).ToString();
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(link, UriKind.Absolute))
            e.Row.Cells["Value"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define your grid columns use the type:  `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL` as the column type.

Then the grid will raise a `CellLinkClicked` event in your code.

Comment: This will change every cell in the column not just the last one.

Comment: You can set the Style on the Cell: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell_members.html

Comment: Link is broken the comment by @alhalama. Basically you can do `cell.Style = ColumnStyle.URL`. Here's the link to the [current documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2014.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v14.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell_members.html), hopefully it won't become broken too soon. (Infragistics needs to fix their documentation, yeeesh!)

Comment: I can't find a reference to any `CellLinkClicked` event.

Comment: You could use the ClickCell event since you are making the cell a hyperlink: http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2014.2/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v14.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~ClickCell_EV.html